# how to make two divs(with img tag)side by side and not aligned vertically when screen size changed

Tags: html, css, image

how to make two divs(with img tag)side by side and not aligned vertically when screen size changed

I have to display two image side by side like this:

```
    <div class="pageView">
        <img id="pagePreview" src="leftImageUrl" class="shadow">
    </div>

    <div class="pageView">
        <img id="pagePreview" nsrc="rightImageUrl" class="shadow">
    </div>
```

it looked well like this:
[image]

but when I display it in smart device,
the two image aligned vertically like this:

[image]

how can i avoid them to aligned vertically , only stay side arrangement??

and in that case, I also want to display the whole two images to fit the view point (to automaticlly change the image's size) like this[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to set the min-width of container wrapping them, lets assume the container wrapping them is `.container` then  you need to write a CSS rule like this.

```
.container{
   min-width: "some number which is greater than sum of width of children"
}
```

this is `fixed width layout` practice of CSS, it will give you a horizontal scroll as width of your `viewport` is less than that of `.container`, not recommended but if it fits it sits.

Answer (score 0):

You can also import bootstrap and then perform this

```
 <div class = "row"> 
  <div class="pageView col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <img id="pagePreview" src="leftImageUrl" class="shadow">
   </div>

   <div class="pageView col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <img id="pagePreview" nsrc="rightImageUrl" class="shadow">
   </div>
</div>
```

Doing this, no matter the size of the screen, both of these divs will always be in the same row.

Comment: Adding to above answer - wrap above code in div with class 'container'. Also, give class - 'img-responsive' to your image tag. It will mkae your images responsive on different browser width.

Comment: @chii, if any of the answers solved your problem please accept that answer.

Comment: @SumeetJain Thank you for your answer.It seemed like the bootstrap get a little conflicked with the base css (used in my company),so maybe I have to try something else.but I will keep it in mind for future use.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<img src="" class="left">
<img src="" class="right">

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%; 
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

if you want the `height` property both are same, set them.